# Stacked Bar Chart in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create stacked Bar Chart in Matplotlib. I have created a simple one using Pandas, but i am now interested in Matplotlib one but cant make it work.

My data

```
    ShiftType   ShiftNumber cnt
0   Non-Standard    1.0 154478
1   Non-Standard    2.0 140421
2   Non-Standard    3.0 159990
3   Standard    1.0 211100
4   Standard    2.0 198652
5   Standard    3.0 190857
```

Code that works using Pandas.

```
df.groupby(by=['ShiftType','ShiftNumber']).size().rename('cnt').unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.legend(title='Shift Numbers', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image: Stacked Bar Chart using Pandas in Python]

How can i get this based on Matplotlib?

Comment: `pandas` uses matplotlib for plotting, so obviously you can recreate this in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html). But this sounds like an x-y problem. Catch the axis object for further image manipulations `ax = df.groupby(by=['ShiftType','...().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`, then change the axis object, e.g., `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)`. BTW, your sample code seems to be incorrect - it does not sum the `cnt` part.

Answer (score 2):

The sample code you provided does not accurately tally the sum.  It's also somewhat unclear what you mean by "create stacked Bar Chart in Matplotlib" as the Pandas plot() function you called is a matplotlib integration.  Regardless, as standard (and possibly best) practice, I regularly use figure and axes to set up my plots.  This allows careful control of the plots which I think you are trying to do here.

I would suggest this code as a solution to your question and starting point for further plot manipulation.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.groupby(['ShiftType', 'ShiftNumber']) \
    ['cnt'].sum() \
    .reset_index() \
    .pivot_table(index='ShiftType', columns='ShiftNumber', values='cnt') \
    .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax)
ax.legend(title='Shift Numbers', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
```

I would then add some standard features that every chart should have, for example a y-label and a title.

```
ax.set_ylabel('cnt')
ax.set_title('Count of Shift Types')
```

Combining those, you will then get this final plot.

[image: ShiftType Stacked Bar Plot]

Answer (score 1):

There might be someting more compact but here is a solution. Here is your df

```
     ShiftType  ShiftNumber     cnt
0  Non-Standard          1.0  154478
1  Non-Standard          2.0  140421
2  Non-Standard          3.0  159990
3      Standard          1.0  211100
4      Standard          2.0  198652
5      Standard          3.0  190857
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))  

m = df['ShiftNumber'].drop_duplicates()
margin_bottom = np.zeros(len(df['ShiftType'].drop_duplicates()))
colors = ["#006D2C", "#31A354","#74C476"]

for num, m in enumerate(m):
    values = list(df[df['ShiftNumber'] == m].loc[:, 'cnt'])

    df[df['ShiftNumber'] == m].plot.bar(x='ShiftType',y='cnt', ax=ax, stacked=True, 
                                    bottom = margin_bottom, color=colors[num], label=m)
    margin_bottom += values

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: does not work! Firstly, the month variable is wrong. I also tried with the example but failed. Please use my df for building a solution.